# Migration path for AngularJS 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written an application using AngularJS 1.0.7. I would like to migrate to AngularJS 1.2. What is the migration path (what issues might I need to fix when migrating)?

Comment: You mean AngularJS 1.2.0? And what does the migration path mean? URL?

Comment: Right, version 1.2.0. Migration path means what should I do to be able to migrate my project to 1.2 (which part of code could be broken, etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The angular team has put together a very comprehensive 1.x to 2.0 migration guide here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Exceptions logged in the console have also been greatly improved. They now include a link to an error reference manual with a detailed explanation of the exception and how to correct it.  You can find the error manual here: http://docs.angularjs.org/error

Answer (score 7):

There is no official guide to migrate from 1.0.7 to 1.2 but the best thing I can find is the changelog through angularJS's versions: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md .

They notice the crucial changes that can break in the new version so you can look into that.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest change you probably need to deal with is on routing: there is now a separate module to handle routing, just as `angular-resource` was already separate. You'll need to load the separate `angular-route.js` file and declare `ngRoute` as a dependency when you create your app. Until you do that, your app will likely be broken. But that was the only major obstacle I faced. (I've heard we should expect this trend to continue, as they break Angular down into smaller, more modular chunks, so people can take what they need, and skip what they don't.)

Beyond that, there are wholesale new features like the Animations module, a bunch of new directives, and some nice new docs. But I'm not yet aware of anything else you'll need to 'migrate', unless you had already implemented some of the new features on the 1.1.x branch. (FWIW, I've collected some additional detail on this stuff on my [blog](http://christianlilley.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/migrating-to-angular-1-2-modular-routing-animations-ng-if-et-al/).)

Comment: I'd also add the changes related to $resource to the *important* ones: "Resource methods return the promise", "Resource promises are resolved with the resource instance". Anyway, the migration guide seems the best reference.

Comment: This is a great comment I'm just noticing. Thanks. It was early days when I wrote the post, and the official migration guide largely trumped my humble effort.